# Creating a git repo for an existing R project - "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master" error

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I want to finally start using version control for my R projects. I started following [this guide](https://hansenjohnson.org/post/sync-github-repository-with-existing-r-project/), created an empty repo, but the problem started when I got to the command line part.

[image]

First I did:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

But after I type:

```
git pull origin master
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
```

Now, if I try the following:

```
git remote -v
```

I get:

```
origin  https://github.com/username/repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/repo_name.git (push)
```

So something is working. I am new to `git` and not sure about where the problem is.

As an attempt to fix the problem, I added one file for the repository (`file.R`) but apart from that, the repository is empty. I get the same error as before.

And if I try `git branch -r` on the terminal I don't get anything in return.

Comment: Did you try `git branch -r` to check which remote branches are known to your local repo?

Comment: I get `repo ` (i.e. the repository name)

Comment: You should get a list of branches prefixed with `origin/`, `origin/master` being one of them.

Comment: How did you clone it? (the command should be in your `history` in case you're unsure)

Comment: I did `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo_name.git`, I have edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started by creating an empty repo in GitHub, then [the default branch is no longer `master`](https://github.com/github/renaming). The default branch is now `main`.

If you started by creating a new repo locally using `git init`, then check what your default branch is using `git branch`. This should show you either a `main` or `master` branch.

It may be easier to create the repo in GitHub with a simple `README.md` and `.gitignore`, then clone that repo to another folder. Move your code into that repo, add and commit everything, then push your code to GitHub.